# jdbcTemplate execute multiple sql statements in one batch

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I'm using Spring jdbcTemplate for my DAO layer. And i have at least two sql statements that i want to execute in a single query to hit the database once:

```
String INSERT_SQL = "INSERT INTO \"ADDRESS\" (id_registred_user, "
                                           + "address, "
                                           + "city, "
                                           + "region, "
                                           + "country) "
                                           + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

String UPDATE_SQL = "UPDATE \"REGISTRED_USER\" SET id_address = ? "
                  + "WHERE id_registred_user = ?";
```

For now i'm doing this inside @Transactional:

```
jdbcTemplate.update(INSERT_SQL, args...);
jdbcTemplate.update(UPDATE_SQL, args...);
```

I know that in simple jdbc there is an addBatch() method, but how can i execute these two sql statements in a single batch using jdbcTemplate? Is there an addBatch() equivalent in jdbcTemplate?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using Spring JdbcTemplate for multiple database operations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564128/using-spring-jdbctemplate-for-multiple-database-operations)

Comment: @pleft His question isn't about multiple databases from what I can tell.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the link I provided is about "how do you perform multiple SQL queries within the same connection?"

Comment: @pleft I never read it...I thought from the title that it was about multiple databases, not multiple operations within a single database...sorry.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen as far as I can tell his question is how to use transactions without transactions, so link is perfectly valid. Fact of used multiple DBs in given link is neglectable.

Answer (score 5):

You could concatenate both queries and add `;` as separator, but this will not make those queries "atomic". In other words, they will not be executed at once as you think, but one after another, just like you would execute 2 templates one by one - no difference here.

To guarantee operation atomicity, you have to use transactions. Transactions can make all changes made by the queries apply at once on transaction commit.