# informix The specified table (t_all) is not in the database?

Tags: java, database, spring, informix

I am using Jdbctemplate to execute the queries with spring.
My database is informix. when i execute the query get the follwing error.

The specified table (t_all) is not in the database.

I think it is because of session disconnection and eventually temp table has gone but i don't know how to fix it.

**Does anyone know what is the actual cause and how to fix this?**

```
SELECT
      mutto                 ,
      apto               ,
      over            ,
      brrnon                ,
      katy                 ,
      sum(e_b-e_re+aan) nettito
FROM muttito_new
WHERE
      aar   = 2019      AND 
      aand  = 04     AND 
      jd     = 1        AND
      vpl_vr = 1 AND (bro < 500 and (mutto < 751 or (mutto > 900 and mutto < 952))) GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5
INTO TEMP t_all;
SELECT       mutto aluta,
      sum(nettito) nettitos
FROM t_all
GROUP BY 1 INTO TEMP t_sel;


jdbcTemplate.execute(selectieQuery());
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently each statement on your SQL string is executed on it's own connection ( I am not sure about this, I am no expert with Spring ). Check [using Spring JdbcTemplate for multiple database operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564128/using-spring-jdbctemplate-for-multiple-database-operations) where they suggest the use of Transactions.